# Hide some columns which are generated dynamically using ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a matrix which contains a group column  header which is generated automatically and always gives as result : `july,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov...June`.

My purpose is how can i modify visibility to get the following result : when the user chooses , for example , `Sep` :  it will only be visible `july,Aug,Sep` , because the actual for the other months is null  .

I can't access to each column individually and makes modification in visibility 
I tried

```
=iif(Fields!actual is nothing , false , true )
```

and

```
=iif(Fields!actual.IsMissing , false , true )
```

but it didn't worked for me

Comment: Just to clarify - is the user setting a parameter value that you want your column grouping value to be less than or equal to? What data types are these values behind the scenes?

Comment: Do you have column groupings? can you add some more information?

Comment: @Sam  I just updated my question .

Comment: Is your parameter selection a date?

Comment: @sam , it is a date .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the user is able to specify the month, isnt he? Therefore, you can add 
a `where` clause in your query

```
where tbl.date_col <= @month_parameter
```

EDIT: The user has applied a visibility expression on the group, instead of doing that over the Textbox

Comment: I need to have all the columns but add a toggle items for which the actual is null .

Comment: have you set the visibility to your group or to the textbox in the tablix

Comment: I set the visibility to the group .

Comment: So you are hiding the group not specific records, try to set it on the textbox and remove the group visibility expression